# dblink from remote server into a Google Cloud SQL instance using .pgpass

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, dblink

I'm trying to connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance using dblink, which works well when setting up my username and password in the connection string, but I would like to save my Client credentials in the SQL instance not to have the need to explicitly put my password in the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .pgpass file which will used is the one that belongs to the OS user which is running the local database ('~/postgres/.pgpass', in most cases).  And then for security reasons, it works only if you are locally a superuser.  Can you meet those criteria?

> but I would like to save my Client credentials in the SQL instance

What does "SQL instance" mean?  I would not think that .pgpass would count as being inside the SQL instance.

An alternative solution is create a foreign server with "postgres_fdw".  This doesn't seem to be documented (edit: it is documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-connect.html), but uses dblink_fdw not postgresql_fdw), but you can pass the name of a "postgres_fdw" foreign server (in single quotes) to dblink functions as the connection string.  It will then pull the password to be used from the USER MAPPING for that server and user.  I would think the USER MAPPING counts as inside the "SQL instance".

Comment: If it needs superuser rights I'm afraid it wont work, I will give a shot to the foreign server example, makes sense, thanks.